# Deleting E-Mails Programmatically with Lua in Neomutt

Tags: lua, mutt, neomutt

Neomutt provides Lua as scripting language. I needed to find e-mails from different senders and delete or move them to different mail folders programmatically. There are Neomutt configuration examples done in Lua but I couldn't find anything similar to my case. Can I do this with Lua in Neomutt? Thanks.